# Tarjeta con Texto en Looker Studio

Tags: google-data-studio

alguien sabe como introducir solo texto en una tarjeta visual en Looker Studio? No quiero números, solo que cuando esté filtrado un campo de mi dataset, la tarjeta muestre otro campo del mismo dataset.

Ej: si filtro un aeropuerto de Argentina, que la tarjeta muestre "Argentina".